# What is wrong with my code?

Tags: jquery

I have 4 links, when each link is clicked, I am taking the index of that link. I am getting `index + 1 = 1, 2, 3 4` like this. According to me when user click on the link, the indexed 'li' need to fadeIn, reset have to fadeOut. so, whatever the link is clicked according to the link index + 1 have to fadeIn, rest should not in the view. for this I wrote this code, but not working. what is wrong with my code ?

```
$('#b-fmg-slider a').each(function(index){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        $('#b-fmg-slider a').removeAttr('class');
        $('#b-fmg-slider ul li').fadeOut();
         $('#b-fmg-slider ul li',':nth-child('+index+1+')').fadeIn();
    })    
})
```

can any one say, whether what I am doing here is wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()` when assigning event handlers. Simply `$('#b-fmg-slider a').click(function...` will do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass in a second parameter, you're actually giving jQuery a context to work on

```
$('#b-fmg-slider ul li',':nth-child('+index+1+')').fadeIn();//does not work
```

Just use the index and a filter

```
var i = $(this).index();
$('#b-fmg-slider ul li:eq(' + i + ')').fadeIn();
```

Here's a simple fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WU7Tt/

Comment: I would simplify that to `$('#b-fmg-slider li').eq(i).fadeIn();`; it's not important, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is can be achieved very easily using an alternative approach. 
First fadeout all the li-s (using a class selector), then fadeIn `$(this)` (the item which was clicked on).

As to why your code is wrong, you are using two separate selectors (if you separate them with a comma, they are separate selectors).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('#b-fmg-slider a').click(function (e) {
  $('#b-fmg-slider ul li').fadeOut();
  $(this).parent('li').next('li').fadeIn();
});
```

Fading out all the li-s and then finding the li which you clicked on (if its not a direct descendant, use [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) instead of [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)), then find the one after it - to fade him in.

Comment: There's only one parent, you don't need to pass a string.